# Can't scroll absolute positioned FlatList when there is nothing behind it

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, react-native-flatlist

## What I'm trying to do:

Make a search bar and show the results in a flat list under the bar.

## What I have:

I have a SearchBar and a FlatList, the FlatList needs to but in absolute position so it covers the content on the bottom of the search bar

## The Problem:

The FlatList is covering the search bar when it's active and I can't scroll the list or select an item. What I noticed is that if i try to select an item or scroll the list when clicking where the SearchBar should be appearing, I can select and scroll the list.

## What I need:

The FlatList to show under the SearchBar and be able to scroll it.
I could use `top: 50` to show the FlatList under the SearchBar but it doesn'r seems good

**Observations:** I'm not that good at styles

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, FlatList } from 'react-native'
import {
    Slider,
    SearchBar,
    ListItem,
} from 'react-native-elements'

export default class SearchForm extends Component {

    state = {
        pages: 1,
        displayList: false,
        itemsPerPage: 5,
    }

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        const {
            data = [],
            itemsPerPage = 5,
        } = this.props


        await fetch('https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/localidades/estados', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.setState({ 
                data: data, 
                displayData: data.slice(0, itemsPerPage) 
            }))

        console.log(this.state.data.length)
    }

    updateSearch = search => {
        const { data, itemsPerPage } = this.state
        let s = search ? search.toLowerCase() : ''
        this.setState({
            displayData: data.filter(res => res.nome.toLowerCase().includes(s)).slice(0, itemsPerPage),
            displayList: true,
            search: search,
            pages: 1,
        })
        if(this.flatListRef){
            this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, offset: 0 })
        }
    }

    loadMore = () => {
        const { pages, displayData, data, search, itemsPerPage } = this.state
        const start = pages * itemsPerPage
        let end = (pages + 1) * itemsPerPage
        let s = search ? search.toLowerCase() : ''
        const newData = data.filter(res => res.nome.toLowerCase().includes(s)).slice(start, end)
        this.setState({
            displayData: [...displayData, ...newData],
            pages: pages + 1,
        })
        console.log(this.state.displayData.length)
    }

    selectItem = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            search: value,
            displayList: false,
        })
    }

    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <ListItem
                style={styles.flatListItem}
                containerStyle={styles.flatListItemCointainer}
                key={index}
                title={item.nome}
                onPress={() => this.selectItem(item.nome)}
            />
        );
    }

    render() {

        const {
            search,
            displayData = [],
            displayList,
        } = this.state

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <SearchBar
                    ref={search => { this.search = search }}
                    placeholder="Type Here..."
                    leftIcon={false}
                    noIcon
                    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
                    value={search}
                />
                {displayList && <FlatList
                    style={styles.flatList}
                    ref={ref => this.flatListRef = ref}
                    data={displayData}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    onEndReached={this.loadMore}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                />}
                <TextInput
                    style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },
    flatList: {
        height: 200,
        width: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    flatListItemCointainer: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
    }
})
```

**Edit:** I just change the code a little bit to show what I'm trying to do. Under the SearchBar will have other components (e.g. TextInput) and when the list is active, the list should go on top of that components.
With Shashin Bhayani answer, it's not going on top of things under it, only pushing it down.

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Comment: @KishanBharda not yet, I kind of stopped trying this. But One thing I know for sure, if you are rendering items inside a `FlatList`, don't add `flex: 1` to it, it will break.

Comment: I am super late but this solved my issue. use `bottom: 0` or any value it will resolve the issue.

Comment: @RajendranNadar That was a life saver! I tried everything I could think of to get the Flatlist to scroll inside an absolute positioned view but nothing worked, except this solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This issue in android, to solve it :

import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `bottom: 0` solved my issue I am using zero because I want the Faltlist to end at the very bottom of the screen it can be any number.

Make sure there is no `flex: 1` in flatlist `style`, `contentContainerStyle` or on the parent flatlist.

Try this and let me know this solved your issue or not.

Comment: Can you help me with my issue: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253810/react-native-flatlist-does-not-scroll-inside-the-custom-bottom-sheet

With bottom: 0, it helps but scroll-bottom-sheet looks weird now.