# React native Flatlist does not scroll inside the custom Animated Bottom sheet

Tags: react-native, flexbox, scrollview, padding, react-native-flatlist

I have created one custom Animated bottom sheet. User can move the bottom sheet scroll up and down. Inside my bottom sheet, I have used flatList where I fetched the data and render the items as a card. Up-till now everything works as expected but I had an issue Flatlist scrolling. Inside the bottom sheet the Flat-list does not scroll. I have made hard coded height value `2000px`, which is really practice and also FlatList's `contentContainerStyle` added hard coded paddingBottom `2000`(also another bad practice). I want to scroll the FlatList based on `Flex-box`. I don't know how to fix this issue.

**I share my code on [expo-snacks](https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/flatlist-scroll)**

**This is my all code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  useWindowDimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
  Button,
  FlatList,
} from "react-native";

import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";

import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

const api =
  "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C10&language_filter=en&limit=50";

export default function App() {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [translateY] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // This is Fetch Dtata
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const data = await response.json();

      setEvent(data.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erro", error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Animation logic
  const bringUpActionSheet = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  const closeDownBottomSheet = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  const bottomSheetIntropolate = translateY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-height / 2.4 + 50, 0],
  });

  const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: bottomSheetIntropolate,
      },
    ],
  };

  const gestureHandler = (e: PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
      closeDownBottomSheet();
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.translationY < 0) {
      bringUpActionSheet();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.container, { top: height * 0.7 }, animatedStyle]}
        >
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
            <ContentConatiner>
              <Title>I am scroll sheet</Title>
              <HeroFlatList
                data={event}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    enabled={true}
                    refreshing={loading}
                    onRefresh={fetchData}
                  />
                }
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                  const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
                  const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;

                  return (
                    <EventContainer key={index}>
                      <EventImage
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            image[0] ||
                            "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
                        }}
                      />
                      <DescriptionContainer>
                        <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
                          {item?.name?.en}
                        </Title>
                        <DescriptionText>
                          {item?.description?.intro ||
                            "No description available"}
                        </DescriptionText>
                        <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
                      </DescriptionContainer>
                    </EventContainer>
                  );
                }}
              />
            </ContentConatiner>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: width,
    height: 800,
  },
});

const HeroFlatList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    padding: 14,
    flexGrow: 1, // IT DOES NOT GROW
    paddingBottom: 2000, // BAD PRACTICE
  },
   height: 2000 /// BAD PRACTICE
})``; 


const ContentConatiner = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
`;
const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
`;

const DateText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #0099cc;
`;

const EventImage = styled.Image`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;

const DescriptionContainer = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
`;

const EventContainer = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.3;
  shadow-radius: 20px;
  shadow-offset: 0 10px;
`;
```

Comment: Do you really want to use PanGestureHandler? Can't you just pass onScroll prop to FlatList and control action sheet animation there?
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#onscroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution what I wanted. Thank you Stack-overflow community. Without your help I could not able to do that.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  useWindowDimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
  Platform
} from "react-native";

import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";

import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");
const IPHONE_DEVICE_START_HEIGHT = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0.4 : 0.6;
const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

const api =
  "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C10&language_filter=en&limit=50";

export default function App() {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const [translateY] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // This is Fetch Dtata
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const data = await response.json();

      setEvent(data.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erro", error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Animation logic
  const bringUpActionSheet = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const closeDownBottomSheet = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  const bottomSheetIntropolate = translateY.interpolate({
   inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [
      height * 0.5 - height / 2.4 + IPHONE_DEVICE_START_HEIGHT,
      height * IPHONE_DEVICE_START_HEIGHT,
    ],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });

  const animatedStyle = {
    top: bottomSheetIntropolate,
    bottom: 0,
  };

  const gestureHandler = (e: PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
      closeDownBottomSheet();
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.translationY < 0) {
      bringUpActionSheet();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.container, { top: height * 0.7 }, animatedStyle]}
        >
              <Title>I am scroll sheet</Title>
              <HeroFlatList
                data={event}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    enabled={true}
                    refreshing={loading}
                    onRefresh={fetchData}
                  />
                }
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                  const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
                  const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;
                  return (
                    <EventContainer key={index}>
                      <EventImage
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            image[0] ||
                            "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
                        }}
                      />
                      <DescriptionContainer>
                        <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
                          {item?.name?.en}
                        </Title>
                        <DescriptionText>
                          {item?.description?.intro ||
                            "No description available"}
                        </DescriptionText>
                        <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
                      </DescriptionContainer>
                    </EventContainer>
                  );
                }}
              />
        
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: width,
    height: 800,
  },
});

const HeroFlatList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
   flexGrow:1
  },

})``; 



const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
`;

const DateText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #0099cc;
`;

const EventImage = styled.Image`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;

const DescriptionContainer = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
`;

const EventContainer = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.3;
  shadow-radius: 20px;
  shadow-offset: 0 10px;
`;
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the updated version of your code. working fine on simulator

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
  LayoutAnimation,
} from "react-native";

import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { PanGestureHandler, FlatList } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("screen");
const extendedHeight = height * 0.7;
const normalHeight = height * 0.4;
const bottomPadding = height * 0.15;

if (
  Platform.OS === "android" &&
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental
) {
  UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
}

const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

const api =
  "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C10&language_filter=en&limit=50";

export default function App() {
  const translateY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const [flatListHeight, setFlatListHeight] = useState(extendedHeight);
  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // This is Fetch Dtata
  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const json = (await response.json()).data;
      setEvent(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erro", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const bottomSheetIntropolate = translateY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-normalHeight, 0],
  });

  const animatedStyle = {
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: bottomSheetIntropolate,
      },
    ],
  };

  const animate = (bringDown) => {
    setFlatListHeight(extendedHeight);
    Animated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: bringDown ? 1 : 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };

  const onGestureEnd = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.linear);
      setFlatListHeight(normalHeight);
    }
  };

  const gestureHandler = (e) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
      animate(true);
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.translationY < 0) {
      animate(false);
    }
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
    const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;
    return (
      <EventContainer key={index}>
        <EventImage
          source={{
            uri:
              image[0] ||
              "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
          }}
        />
        <DescriptionContainer>
          <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
            {item?.name?.en}
          </Title>
          <DescriptionText>
            {item?.description?.intro || "No description available"}
          </DescriptionText>
          <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
        </DescriptionContainer>
      </EventContainer>
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler} onEnded={onGestureEnd}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[styles.container, { top: height * 0.7 }, animatedStyle]}
        >
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.wrapper}>
            <ContentConatiner>
              <Title>I am scroll sheet</Title>
              <HeroFlatList
                style={{ height: flatListHeight }}
                data={event}
                ListFooterComponent={() => (
                  <View style={{ height: bottomPadding }} />
                )}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    enabled={true}
                    refreshing={loading}
                    onRefresh={fetchData}
                  />
                }
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={renderItem}
              />
            </ContentConatiner>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </Animated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: width,
    height: 800,
  },
});

const HeroFlatList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
    padding: 14,
    flexGrow: 1, // IT DOES NOT GROW
  },
})``;

const ContentConatiner = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
`;
const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
`;

const DateText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #0099cc;
`;

const EventImage = styled.Image`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;

const DescriptionContainer = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
`;

const EventContainer = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.3;
  shadow-radius: 20px;
  shadow-offset: 0 10px;
`;
```

Things I have updated in your code

1. useRef instead of useState for holding animated value
2. Replaced inline closure with const for renderItem (this can simplify the JSX and improve the performance)
3. Unified your animation const to one.
4. Utilised onEnded prop to decrease the height of FlatList gracefully with the help of LayoutAnimation
5. Since you were accessing the width from Dimensions, the height can also be fetched from the same resource i.e. removed the hook
6. updated the translateY logic calculation and Flatlist height to percentage base
7. `listFooterItem` to provide some padding to last item
8. A minor update to your fetch logic

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to figure this out for me. But seems like the `FlatList` items do not scroll in Android Emulator. You can test your code in here:  https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/vigorous-cake

Comment: @Krisna you are right, I had only checked in iOS simulator. not sure why it's not scrolling in Android Emulator. will try this on weekend to find what's wrong with the code lol

Comment: try to use FlatList from react-native-gesture-handler. then it will work. Idk why but it worked

Comment: @Krisna thanks for the feedback, I have updated the snippet accordingly. Can you please let me know if the above code meets your expectations?

Comment: I already test it and it works as expect : ). I upvoted it already. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

If you're not against using `react-native-reanimated`, then I've made a minimally modified version of your code that should do exactly what you want.

I use Reanimated's v1 compatibility API, so you don't have to install the babel transpiler or anything. It should work as-is.
https://snack.expo.dev/@switt/flatlist-scroll-reanimated

[image: Example of working code]

Reanimated is a better fit here, because React-Native's native Animated module cannot animate the `top`, `bottom`, `width`, `height`, etc. properties, it'd likely require setting `useNativeDriver` to `false` for what you're trying to achieve. That would lead to some performance drops/choppy frames during animation.

Here's your edited code just for convenience

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  useWindowDimensions,
  SafeAreaView,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
  Button,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";

import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import styled from "styled-components";

import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import Reanimated, { EasingNode } from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen");

const initialRegion = {
  latitudeDelta: 15,
  longitudeDelta: 15,
  latitude: 60.1098678,
  longitude: 24.7385084,
};

const api =
  "http://open-api.myhelsinki.fi/v1/events/?distance_filter=60.1699%2C24.9384%2C10&language_filter=en&limit=50";

export default function App() {
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const translateY = React.useRef(new Reanimated.Value(0)).current;

  const [event, setEvent] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  // This is Fetch Dtata
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch(api);
      const data = await response.json();

      setEvent(data.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("erro", error);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // Animation logic
  const bringUpActionSheet = () => {
    Reanimated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
    }).start();
  };
  const closeDownBottomSheet = () => {
    Reanimated.timing(translateY, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
      easing: EasingNode.inOut(EasingNode.ease)
    }).start();
  };
  
  const bottomSheetTop = translateY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [height * 0.7 - height / 2.4 + 50, height * 0.7]
  });
  const animatedStyle = {
    top: bottomSheetTop,
    bottom: 0
  };

  const gestureHandler = (e: PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.translationY > 0) {
      closeDownBottomSheet();
    } else if (e.nativeEvent.translationY < 0) {
      bringUpActionSheet();
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} initialRegion={initialRegion} />
      <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
        <Reanimated.View
          style={[styles.container, { top: height * 0.7 }, animatedStyle]}
        >
              <Title>I am scroll sheet</Title>
              <HeroFlatList
                data={event}
                refreshControl={
                  <RefreshControl
                    enabled={true}
                    refreshing={loading}
                    onRefresh={fetchData}
                  />
                }
                keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                  const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
                  const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;
                  return (
                    <EventContainer key={index}>
                      <EventImage
                        source={{
                          uri:
                            image[0] ||
                            "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
                        }}
                      />
                      <DescriptionContainer>
                        <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
                          {item?.name?.en}
                        </Title>
                        <DescriptionText>
                          {item?.description?.intro ||
                            "No description available"}
                        </DescriptionText>
                        <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
                      </DescriptionContainer>
                    </EventContainer>
                  );
                }}
              />
        </Reanimated.View>
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOffset: {
      height: -6,
      width: 0,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.1,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    borderTopEndRadius: 15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
  },
  mapStyle: {
    width: width,
    height: 800,
  },
});

const HeroFlatList = styled(FlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
  paddingBottom: 50
  },
  // height:510,
  // flex:1
})``; 



const Title = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
`;

const DescriptionText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.7;
`;

const DateText = styled(Title)`
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  color: #0099cc;
`;

const EventImage = styled.Image`
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
`;

const DescriptionContainer = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
`;

const EventContainer = styled(Animated.View)`
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  shadow-color: #000;
  shadow-opacity: 0.3;
  shadow-radius: 20px;
  shadow-offset: 0 10px;
`;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to figure this out for me. I am not  against using `react-native-reanimated` but their package is bit annoying because they change the props every 2 to 3 months. I am still trying to learn the RN's own Animate. If you can give me the solution in my code, what is the wrong that would be awesome and learning for me. The issue I have is part of the Flatlist item does not scroll outside the screen. I think I have wrong animatedStyle calculations.Still trying to figure it out. Again , I appreciate the detailed response.

Comment: I see you've already figured out what's wrong in your own answer. But I'll just answer here again just for completeness then.

Comment: The `top` prop provided in your original code caused the Animated.View to be rendered with part of it offscreen, so, as you have done so in your answer, providing `bottom` prop helps constrain it.

I can assure you that Reanimated is pretty stable, my codebase has been relying on Reanimated for > 1 year, and been through the jump from v1 to v2, which was painless.
Changing props was likely while v2 was in Beta, but it has been stable for a long time.

P.S. If you find the answer helpful please consider upvoting ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code,

You need to change

```
import {
  PanGestureHandler,
  PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList as GFlatList
} from "react-native-gesture-handler";
```

Import FlatList from react-native-gesture-handler and update your code as below,

```
const HeroFlatList = styled(GFlatList).attrs({
  contentContainerStyle: {
  paddingBottom: 50
  },
  height:510,
})``;
```

I have tested this on your code and it works. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Janak, But the issue is when you scroll the  animated bottom sheet down and try to scroll the items. it does not show last items of the flatlist(I need to  increase hard coded `height` and `paddingBottom`). I want to use this bottom sheet as a re-useable component. Is there anyway I can use flexbox instead of hard coded `height`  and `paddingBottom`. The main purpose of this question is how to make this flatlist styling more efficient than hard coded height and paddingBottom

https://snack.expo.dev/@alakdam/scroll

Answer (score -1):

keep HeroFlatList in scrollView.

```
<ScrollView>
  <HeroFlatList
    data={event}
    refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      enabled={true}
      refreshing={loading}
      onRefresh={fetchData}
     />
    }
    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
      const image = item?.description.images.map((img) => img.url);
      const startDate = item?.event_dates?.starting_day;
      return (
        <EventContainer key={index}>
          <EventImage
            source={{
              uri:
                image[0] || "https://res.cloudinary.com/drewzxzgc/image/upload/v1631085536/zma1beozwbdc8zqwfhdu.jpg",
             }}
          />
          <DescriptionContainer>
             <Title ellipsizeMode="tail" numberOfLines={1}>
                {item?.name?.en}
             </Title>
             <DescriptionText>
                {item?.description?.intro || "No description available"}
             </DescriptionText>
             <DateText>{startDate}</DateText>
          </DescriptionContainer>
       </EventContainer>
     );
   }}
 />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did  not you get any warning like this: `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

Comment: No, I can't get any errors. Please check here is full expo link: https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/001cbe

Comment: Can you able to see the last item of the flatlist. I can't see

Comment: ok.. I got it. The last record title is Unikuskit, Right? Here is the full code: https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/001cbe

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think it's not optimal solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66939975/react-native-virtualizedlists-should-never-be-nested-inside-plain-scrollviews